# Relative Path Perspective

Tags: node.js, path, relative-path

If I have a directory structure like this

```
/dir
  /test
    /symlink-package.json
  /pacakge.json
```

And I run the ideal code or function I'm looking for from the `dir` directory, this is the output I'd like.

```
var lens = "./test"
var path = "./package.json"

> ./test/package.json

var lens = "./test"
var path = "../package.json"

> ./package.json
```

Where `lens` is the directory you wish to see through as, and the return value is the resulting path in the perspective of the current directory.

Does node's path offer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> path.join("./test","./package.json")
'test/package.json'
> path.join("./test","../package.json")
'package.json'
```

Comment: You can also use `__dirname` to specify the current directory: `path.join(__dirname, 'test', '..', 'package.json')`